# Program sorting data into one of two categories based on 'experience'?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Suppose I have a whole set of recipes in text format, with nothing else about them being known in advance. I must divide this data into 'recipes for baked goods' and 'other recipes'.

For a baked good, an excerpt from the recipe might read thusly:

"Add the flour to the mixing bowl followed by the two beaten eggs, a pinch of salt and baking powder..."

These have all been written by different authors, so the language and vocabulary is not consistent. I am in need of an algorithm or, better still, an existing machine learning library (implementation language is not an issue) that I can 'teach' to distinguish between these two types of recipe.

For example I might provide it with a set of recipes that I know are for baked goods, and it would be able to analyse these in order to gain the ability to make an estimate as to whether a new recipe it is presented with falls into this category.

Getting the correct answer is not critical, but should be reasonably reliable. Having researched this problem it is clear to me that my AI/ML vocabulary is not extensive enough to allow me to refine my search.

Can anyone suggest a few libraries, tools or even concepts/algorithms that would allow me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is anomaly / outlier detection.

In your example, "baked goods" is the data you are interested in, and anything that doesn't look like what you have seen before (not a baked good)  is an anomaly / outlier.

scikit learn has a limited number of methods for this. Another common method is to compute the average distance between data points, and then anything new that is more than the average + c*standard deviation is considered an outlier.

More sophisticated methods exist as well.

Comment: This answer got me started looking into SVM, specifically https://github.com/camspiers/statistical-classifier which is built on http://pecl.php.net/package/svm running http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ at its core. Using the Composer package, it turned out to be trivial to train an SVM to recognise the difference between baked goods and non-baked goods simply by providing it with known examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try case based reasoning.

Extract specific words or phrases that would put a recipe into the baked goods category. If it is not there it must be in other recipes.

You can get clever and add word sets {} so you don't need to look for a phrase.
Add weighting to each word and if it gets over a value put it into baked.

So {"oven" => "10", "flour" = > "5", "eggs" => "3"}

My reasoning is that if it is going in the "oven" it is likely to be getting baked.  If you are going to distinguish between baking a cake and roasting a join then, this needs adjusted.  Likewise "flour" is associated with something that is going to be baked as are eggs.

add pairs {("beaten", "eggs") => "5"} notice this is different from a phrase {"beaten eggs" => "10"} in that the worst in the pairs can appear anywhere in the recipe.

negatives {"chill in the fridge" => -10}

negators {"dust with flour" => "-flour"}

absolutes {"bake in the oven"  => 10000} is just a way of saying {"bake in the oven"  => "it is a baked good"} by having the number so high it will be over the threshold on its' own.